# Provisioning a Gitlab CI VirtualBox Runner with Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, gitlab

**1) Context**

I am running a build pipeline using Gitlab's VirtualBox runner (Gitlab version 10.6.3). When I manually create a base image (e.g. `my-base-vm`), then the build runs perfectly on the `1-n` clones that Gitlab-CI creates.

**2) Observed error**

However, when I want to provision the base image using Vagrant (version 2.2.2), the Gitlab CI build ouput for my job shows the following:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.2.0 (35e8515d)
  on myproject-build-machine 1c8ab769
Using VirtualBox version 5.2.18_Ubuntur123745 executor...
Creating new VM...
ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:35542->127.0.0.1:34963: read: connection reset by peer
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using VirtualBox version 5.2.18_Ubuntur123745 executor...
Creating new VM...
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```

The image is based on the base image `ubuntu/bionic64`.

**3) Configuration**

The runner (clone from `my-base-vm`) seems to have the right NAT rules though (output of `VBoxManage showvminfo my-base-vm-runner-1c8ab769-concurrent-0`):

```
NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = guestssh, protocol = tcp, host ip = 127.0.0.1, host port = 32805, guest ip = , guest port = 22
NIC 1 Rule(1):   name = ssh, protocol = tcp, host ip = 127.0.0.1, host port = 2222, guest ip = , guest port = 22
```

The Gitlab `config.toml` is configured with the correct username + password (`vagrant:vagrant`) and the Vagrant file provisions the machine to accept username and password as means of authentication (excerpt from `Vagrantfile`):

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        sed -i 's/ChallengeResponseAuthentication no/ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        service ssh restart
    SHELL
```